# NGINX (Reverse Proxy - Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I searched a lot and tried a lot but on this point I dont get it... so here is my question:

I have a newly setup Proxmox and I wanna run a nginx reverse proxy and some VMs behind it. It is the first time with nginx and reverse proxy for me. I only used Apache before and never a reverse proxy.

So my reverse proxy has basicly three files: headers.conf, ssl.conf and my.domain.com.conf.

In headers.conf is the following:

```
#
# Add headers to serve security related headers
#  
# HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required)
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload;" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Robots-Tag none always;
add_header X-Download-Options noopen always;
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none always;
add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer always;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;

# Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

#prox headers
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

Then there is the ssl.conf:

```
  GNU nano 5.4                                                                     /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf                                                                              
#
# Configure SSL
#

# Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 4096 bits
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams/dhparams.pem;

# Not using TLSv1 will break:
# Android <= 4.4.40 IE <= 10 IE mobile <=10
# Removing TLSv1.1 breaks nothing else!
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

# SSL ciphers: RSA + ECDSA
# Two certificate types (ECDSA, RSA) are needed.
ssl_ciphers 'TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-A>

# Use multiple curves.
ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1:secp384r1;

# Server should determine the ciphers, not the client
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# SSL session handling
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

# SSL stapling has to be done seperately, becuase it will not work with self signed certs
# OCSP Stapling fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

# DNS resolver
resolver 192.168.xxx.xx;
```

and the my.domain.com.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.domain.com;

location ~ \.* {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name my.domain.com;

        # SSL configuration
        # RSA certificates
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/my.domain.com/rsa/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/my.domain.com/rsa/key.pem;
        # ECC certificates
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/my.domain.com/ecc/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/my.domain.com/ecc/key.pem;

        # This should be ca.pem (certificate with the additional intermediate certificate)
        # See here: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html
        # ECC
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/my.domain.com/ecc/ca.pem;

        # Include SSL configuration
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

        # Include headers
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/headers.conf;

        # Set the access log location
        access_log            /var/log/nginx/my.domain.access.log;


location ~ \.* {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.xxx:80;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;
                proxy_redirect http://192.168.xxx.xxx:80 https://my.domain.com;
        }
}
```

That is the reverse proxy side.

The VM has nginx as well and the following file, my.domain.com.conf:

```
upstream php-handler {
    server unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    #root /var/www;


#       location / {
#               return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#       }


        # Path to the root of your installation
        root /var/www/nextcloud;

        # Specify how to handle directories -- specifying `/index.php$request_uri`
        # here as the fallback means that Nginx always exhibits the desired behaviour
        # when a client requests a path that corresponds to a directory that exists
        # on the server. In particular, if that directory contains an index.php file,
        # that file is correctly served; if it doesn't, then the request is passed to
        # the front-end controller. This consistent behaviour means that we don't need
        # to specify custom rules for certain paths (e.g. images and other assets,
        # `/updater`, `/ocm-provider`, `/ocs-provider`), and thus
        # `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri`
        # always provides the desired behaviour.
        index index.php index.html /index.php$request_uri;

               # set max upload size and increase upload timeout:
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    client_body_timeout 300s;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        # Rule borrowed from `.htaccess` to handle Microsoft DAV clients
        location = / {
                if ( $http_user_agent ~ ^DavClnt ) {
                        return 302 /remote.php/webdav/$is_args$args;
                }
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # Make a regex exception for `/.well-known` so that clients can still
        # access it despite the existence of the regex rule
        # `location ~ /(\.|autotest|...)` which would otherwise handle requests
        # for `/.well-known`.
        location ^~ /.well-known {
                # The rules in this block are an adaptation of the rules
                # in `.htaccess` that concern `/.well-known`.

                location = /.well-known/carddav { return 301 /remote.php/dav/; }
                location = /.well-known/caldav  { return 301 /remote.php/dav/; }

                #location /.well-known/acme-challenge    { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
                #location /.well-known/pki-validation    { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }

                # Let Nextcloud's API for `/.well-known` URIs handle all other
                # requests by passing them to the front-end controller.
                return 301 /index.php$request_uri;
        }

        # Rules borrowed from `.htaccess` to hide certain paths from clients
        location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)(?:$|/)  { return 404; }
        location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console)                { return 404; }

        # Ensure this block, which passes PHP files to the PHP process, is above the blocks
        # which handle static assets (as seen below). If this block is not declared first,
        # then Nginx will encounter an infinite rewriting loop when it prepends `/index.php`
        # to the URI, resulting in a HTTP 500 error response.
        location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
        # Required for legacy support
        rewrite ^/(?!index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+|.+\/richdocumentscode\/proxy) /index.php$request_uri;

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;

                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

                fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;         # Avoid sending the security headers twice
                fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;     # Enable pretty urls
                fastcgi_pass php-handler;

                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_request_buffering off;

                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;

                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 10G
                        post_max_size = 10G
                        max_execution_time = 3600
                        output_buffering = off";
        }
        location ~ \.(?:css|js|svg|gif|png|jpg|ico|wasm|tflite)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        expires 6M;         # Cache-Control policy borrowed from `.htaccess`
        access_log off;     # Optional: Don't log access to assets

        location ~ \.wasm$ {
            default_type application/wasm;
        }
    }

        location ~ \.woff2?$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
                expires 7d;         # Cache-Control policy borrowed from `.htaccess`
                access_log off;     # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        }

        # Rule borrowed from `.htaccess`
        location /remote {
                return 301 /remote.php$request_uri;
        }

}
```

I did all that from reading different tutorials and the manuals itself. But I totally don't get my mistake.... is there anything obvies you can see? I feel very happy for any hint you guys have for me!

Thank you a lot and good christmas time :)

Comment: nginx usually reports "Bad Gateway" when it can not access the `proxy_pass` server. so do nginx have access to `192.168.xxx.xxx:80` (i assume you have masked the ip with xxx.xxx ?) - try with `telnet 192.168.xxx.xxx 80` and write `GET /`.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. Yes, that was me masking it... its a habbit.

Comment: ok, but the `proxy_redirect` is translating `http` to `https` even though you vm nginx only serves `http`.

Comment: okay yes and that is wrong right? the redirect should be http only right?

Comment: yes, keep same protocol (http)

Comment: makes defenetly sense. then the only line to chage so far is:  proxy_redirect http://192.168.xxx.xxx:80 https://my.domain.com; to  proxy_redirect http://192.168.xxx.xxx:80 http://my.domain.com;

Answer (score -1):

This is the output:

```
root@HL-Reverse-Proxy:/var/www# telnet 192.168.178.100 80
Trying 192.168.178.100...
Connected to 192.168.178.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.4</center>
</body>
</html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So connection is possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).